# Ambiguous column name error ONLY ON ONE DB with compatibility level 90

Tags: sql-server

I have issue to work on.

Query is like -

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2
FROM table1 t 
inner join table2 t2 on <join condition>
GROUP BY column1, column2.
```

column1 and column2 are present in table1 as well as table2.

Alias is used in select query but NOT USED in group by clause `t.column1`, `t.column2`.

This code fails only for one database and works fine on other databases.

I tried changing its `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 90`. but it didn't work.

My question is **why it is not working on one particular db** and works fine on others?

Comment: which version of sqlserver are you using?

Comment: when it is not working. You have said "Alias is not used" but you have used alias `t.column1, t.column2`

Comment: Posting a dummy query might be masking the real issue. Can you provide an actual example as well as the complete error message, please?

Comment: i'm suggesting you ***could*** try this (as i can't say without the actual query); have you tried removing your tables' alias? (like, removing the 't' at the end?)

Comment: If column1 (the actual name) exists in both tables, you will get the error. That is why you need to use the alias. SQL 101

Comment: Are all the databases on the same server? Are they all on the same instance on that server? Do they all have the same compatibility level? Are you sure the schema and query are the same on each database? If it works on one database and not another there must be a difference?

Comment: @user1049021 instead of focusing on what setting causes this failure, you should write the code **correctly**. Any time you are using an alias, *all* columns referenced in that table should include the alias. In fact, in any query with more than one object (table/view) should include aliases for **all** columns.

Answer (score 1):

You're making multiple 'duplicate columns' in your query.

SQL Server doesn't know if you're referencing `T.column1` or `column1` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

As link in comments said:

> It doesn't know which occurence you want to sort on - and it obviously doesn't realize that both occurences refer to the same column.

---

In order to 'tackle' this, you need to use the same naming in your `GROUP BY` as you did in your select.

Making your query:

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2
FROM table1 t 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON <join condition>
GROUP BY t.column1, t.column2
```

---

you may find it works happily enough with something like:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1  
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

As you are only initiating each of the columns **once**.

---

If, for example, both of your tables contain the column ID, and you wanted to `SELECT` only one of them, then you would have to use alias' **for all columns**.

Something like:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.column2
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.column2
```

Comment: I agree but then exception should occur for all database why only on one database

Comment: one database or one table?

Comment: I am saying same query throws excption only on one database but works fine on other databases